# Relation between okhttp and HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, okhttp

Many people talk to me that HttpURLConnection is based on okhttp from android 4.4 on.

But  when I dive into codes of okhttp, the OkHttpURLConnection is a subclass extended from  HttpURLConnection.

So, okhttp is based on HttpURLConnection or HttpURLConnection is based on okhttp?

And I find that HttpURLConnection's implement come from rt.jar which is from jdk.

I hope someone can tell me the real relation between okhttp and HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 9):

> And I find that HttpURLConnection's implement come from rt.jar which is from jdk.

No. Android does not use `rt.jar`, at compile time or at runtime.

> okhttp is based on HttpURLConnection or HttpURLConnection is based on okhttp?

Android's concrete implementation of the `abstract` class named `HttpURLConnection` is based on a fork of OkHttp, as of Android 4.4.

`HttpURLConnection` itself is not tied to OkHttp; `HttpURLConnection` existed before Google or Square did. But `HttpURLConnection` is an `abstract` class — it is useless on its own. A Java runtime library needs a concrete implementation of `HttpURLConnection`, which it can then use to implement methods like `openConnection()` on `URL`, which needs to return some `HttpURLConnection` implementation.

FWIW, in Android 4.3 and older, the concrete implementation of `HttpURLConnection`, AFAIK, was based on the Apache Harmony implementation, the way that most `java.*` and `javax.*` classes in Android were.

Comment: Great answer! And OkHttp itself started out as a fork of that same Apache Harmony implementation!

Comment: @CommonsWare so is it correct to say that, since that fork of OkHttp back at Android 4.4, OkHttp and HttpURLConnection have diverged?  I'm particularly interested in using OkHttp because it "perseveres when the network is troublesome: it will silently recover from common connection problems", since I'm having some problems with some users of my app which I suspect relate to connectivity issues during a bitmap fetch using HttpURLConnection.  But if HttpURLConnection uses the same "perseverance" techniques as OkHttp, there is no point.

Comment: @drmrbrewer: "so is it correct to say that, since that fork of OkHttp back at Android 4.4, OkHttp and HttpURLConnection have diverged?" -- I haven't run any diffs, so I have no idea what OkHttp changes have been adopted by the AOSP. At minimum, as a library, current versions of OkHttp will be newer than some versions of Android. It might be newer than all versions of Android. In terms of converting your code... migrate for the better API, stay for the hopefully better connection handling. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare "the better API" being OkHttp?  Complicated a little by them recently dropping support for Android 4 (except via a separate branch that will at least be supported until end of Dec 2020... see https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5-818bb78d07ce)... so it would be moving to an API that will in due course be deprecated (if I wish to continue supporting Android 4).  (Who would want to be a developer?)

Comment: @drmrbrewer: ""the better API" being OkHttp?" -- yes. `HttpUrlConnection` is kinda ancient as programming patterns go. Your point regarding version support is valid; mentally, I've moved to `minSdkVersion 21` since late last year, given that it is ~90% of the Play ecosystem.

Comment: @CommonsWare yep although 10% is still a significant proportion to drop.  Is there any way of using the `3.12` branch for `sdk<21` and `3.13` for `sdk>=21`, a bit like it would be possible to use `HttpUrlConnection` for `sdk<21` and `OkHttp` for `sdk>=21`?

Comment: @drmrbrewer: I don't know of a good way to do that -- you might want to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question regarding that.